# Easiest way to check for null and empty string on a TypeScript number

Tags: typescript

I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked, so maybe I'm overlooking the obvious. I have a form field that is supposed to be a number. Its starting value is null, but once a number is entered and cleared, its an empty string. It looks like JavaScript treats "" like 0 for numeric purposes.

So, instead of saying...

```html
if ((this.RetailPrice != null && this.RetailPrice != 0) || this.RetailPrice === 0) {
        return this.RetailPrice;
      }
```

Is there a way to extend the TypeScript number type to have a IsNullOrEmpty() method? Or something similar that would simplify this expression?

---

**Ultimately, I think I was looking for something as simple as...**

```
if (this.RetailPrice) {

}
```

Comment: How are you setting the value for `this.RetailPrice`?

Comment: Binding with Angular's ng-model on an input (type=number). I define it as a number within my controller (written in TypeScript).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply use typeof. It will check undefined, null, 0 and "" also.

```
if(typeof RetailPrice!='undefined' && RetailPrice){
   return this.RetailPrice;
}
```

Comment: What difference is there between your code and simply  if (RetailPrice) ?

Comment: if(RetailPrice) will throw a javascript exception if the variable RetailPrice has never been declared - if(typeof RetailPrice!='undefined' && RetailPrice) will avoid that.

Comment: Shouldn't you use !== for this string comparison?

Comment: Downvoted. 1. use `strict` checks to avoid `javascript`s "to falsy" type conversion 2. typescript will not compile when variable is used before it's declaration.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, it doesn't work with strings. TS throws an exception: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: @marisks This worked for me. Maybe it was a bug that has now been addressed in a subsequent version of TypeScript?

Answer (score 22):

To excludes blank strings as well

```js
if(this.retailPrice && this.retailPrice.trim()){
   //Implement your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Numeric field requires a bit different condition:
if (typeof(numValue) === 'undefined' || numValue == null) {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

For typescript users looking to generally distinguish between falsy and non-falsy, and are comfortable installing a (small) package, I've found [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#falsy) very useful.

```js
import { isFalsy } from 'utility-types'

if (!isFalsy(foo)) {
  // do something with foo, which you (and the compiler)
  // know is not false | "" | 0 | null | undefined
}
```